# Related rates problem on spherical cap

Tags: calculus

I am trying to solve the following:

> Water flows into a hemispherical tank of radius $10$ feet (flat side up). At any instant, let $h$ denote the depth of the water, measured from the bottom, $r$ the radius of the surface of the water, and $V$ the volume of the water in the tank. Compute $\frac{dV}{dh}$ at the instant when $h=5$ feet. If the water flows in at a constant rate of $5\sqrt3$ cubic feet per second, compute $\frac{dr}{dt}$, the rate at which $r$ is changing, at the instant when $h=5$ feet.

Since $V=\pi h^2(R-\frac{h}{3})$, where $R=10$ feet, $\frac{dV}{dh}=\pi h(20-h)$, so $\frac{dV}{dh}=75\pi$ feet when $h=5$ feet.

I am not sure how to calculate $\frac{dr}{dt}$.

If I use $h=R+\sqrt{R^2+r^2}$, then $V=\frac{\pi}{3}(2R^3+2(R^2+r^2)^{3/2}+3Rr^2)$, so $\frac{dV}{dt}=2\pi r\frac{dr}{dt}(R+\sqrt{R^2+r^2})$.

Since $r=\sqrt{h(2R-h)}$, $\frac{dr}{dt}=\frac{1}{10\pi}$ feet per second.

However, the answer should be $\frac{dr}{dt}=\frac{1}{15\pi}$ feet per second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got your units mixed up along the way – usually it's a good idea to either drop all units or to carry units along everywhere; mixing the two approaches is a recipe for confusion. In $20-h$, you omitted the unit "feet" on the $20$, but then in $\frac{\mathrm dV}{\mathrm dh}=75\pi$ feet you partially introduced it again. The dimensions of $\frac{\mathrm dV}{\mathrm dh}$ are length squared, so the units must be squared feet.

In the rest of the calculation, $h=R+\sqrt{R^2+r^2}$ should be $h=R-\sqrt{R^2-r^2}$. The first minus sign is because $h$ is below, not above $R$, and the second minus sign is because $r$ and $R-h$ are the legs and $R$ is the hypothenuse.